# When am I allowed to use the "request" object in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass an instance of the current user using "request.user", but when I try to access the "request" object where I need to, I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

When I try to use self.request.user I get a similar error (PasswordChangeForm inherits SetPasswordForm):

```
AttributeError: 'PasswordChangeForm' object has no attribute 'request'
```

---

This is form class I use (request usage in def __init__ ):

```
class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
"""
A form that lets a user change set their password without entering the old
password
"""
error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
}
new_password1 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("New password"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    strip=False,
    help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
)
new_password2 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("New password confirmation"),
    strip=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput,
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = request.user
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_new_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
    if password1 and password2:
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
    password_validation.validate_password(password2, self.user)
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    password = self.cleaned_data["new_password1"]
    self.user.set_password(password)
    if commit:
        self.user.save()
    return self.user
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` object is accessible in views (and templates, if necessary context processor is on), not in forms. You should pass `request.user` (or `self.request.user` in case of class-based views) to form's constructor and thus set its processing in your form's `__init__` method.

Btw, I don't know why you are copying [built-in form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L298) and changing things in it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you Roman. So would I not be able to simply add the ContextMixin as such: class SetPasswordForm(ContextMixin, forms.Form):  --and if so, what are the consequences? Any possible security flaws?

Comment: @willer2k ContextMixin (as well as all the other built-in Django mixins, AFAIK) is for [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/), not for forms. So if you use mixin for CBV with form class, it will probably lead to some non-sense behaviour